# Why does my code take 1000x longer to sort lists of 2 than 4

Tags: python

I’m trying to time how long it takes for the selectionsort code to sort a list of length 2^i but for some reason it takes longer to sort 2^1 than 2^2 by a fair margin.

```
import random
import time

def selectionsort(mylist):
    sortedlist=[]
    while len(mylist) > 0:
        lowest = mylist[0]
        for i in mylist:
            if i < lowest:
                lowest=i
        sortedlist.append(lowest)
        mylist.remove(lowest)
    return sortedlist

mylist = []
ivalues = []
sorttimelist = []
for i in range(2):
    ivalues.append(2**i)
    for x in range(2**i):
        mylist.append(random.random())
    start_time=time.perf_counter()
    selectionsort(mylist)
    end_time=time.perf_counter()
    sorttime=end_time-start_time
    sorttimelist.append(sorttime)
    mylist.clear()
print(sorttimelist)
```

Using print just to test it’s going correctly.

Comment: Please ensure your example is complete - enough code that someone else can run it. Here, you are calling `selectionsort(mylist)` and later doing `mylist.clear()`, apparently using a global `mylist` that isn't shown here. Anyway, you should use the standard library `timeit` module for performance timing rather than trying to do it yourself.

Comment: Why destroy the list in the process of sorting it? You should be able to avoid `remove` (which is inefficient).

Comment: Testing like this, with a single test iteration and such small data sizes, is meaningless.  My guess is that the first test is "warming up" the system and so takes longer.  Whichever test you run second will be faster due to this.  Try reversing the order of the tests, and I bet you get different results.  Also, try doing each test 1000 times in a loop and compare those times.

Answer (score 1):

Testing like this, with a single test iteration and such small data sizes, is meaningless. My guess is that the first test is "warming up" the system and so takes longer. Whichever test you run second will be faster due to this.

I enhanced your code to run each test 10000 times, totaling the individual times.  When I do this, the second number is larger than the first every time I run it.  Here's the new test code:

```
sorttimelist = []
for i in range(2):
    total_time = 0
    for iter in range(10000):
        mylist = []
        for x in range(2 ** i):
            mylist.append(random.random())
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        selectionsort(mylist)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        sorttime = end_time - start_time
        total_time += sorttime
        mylist.clear()
    sorttimelist.append(total_time)

print(sorttimelist)
```

And a few sample results:

```
[0.0065520769999985184, 0.0096335120000004]
[0.00565655999999945,   0.009094481000001708]
[0.005614095000000513,  0.00950561699999955]
```